# what are the different versions of miluiyim for the Hebrew letters?

Tags: aleph-bet-letters, gematria-numerology

When calculating gematrias for the Hebrew letters there are letter expansions called "miluyim".

what are all the valid miluiyim letter expansions 
according to chazal? (ex. midrashim, talmud, zohar, arizal, ramak, rashash, and the like)

please source.

this [site](https://nifla-ot.co.il/2016/01/27/%D7%A9%D7%A2%D7%A8-%D7%9C%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%9D-%D7%94%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%98%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94/) brings some examples at #8 (labeled "אות במילואה") but does not give any references